# Send command to :terminal buffer in Vim?

Tags: terminal, shell

I used `:term` to open a new integrated split terminal window. The problem is, using `:! <cmd>` opens a new buffer which takes the entire screen, runs the shell command, then waits for me to press any key.

Is there any way I can send a command directly to the terminal without having to switch focus to it?

Comment: I wrote a vimscript function and command for this: https://balki.me/posts/vim-stt/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:!` runs the command in a (usually non-interactive) shell.  See [chapter 21 of the user manual](https://vimhelp.org/usr_21.txt.html#21.2) and `:h :!` for more information.

This is different to `:term` which runs an interactive terminal in a vim window.  This is a relative new feature which vim needs to have been compiled with, the details of which can be found at `:h terminal`.  If you want to type in the terminal window without switching to it then `term_sendkeys()` may be useful.

Comment: I was hoping it would be slightly more approachable. I settled to use [neoterm](https://github.com/kassio/neoterm) instead.